# how implement jstree-actions

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have the following doubt since I'm just starting to use the jstree
I see that there is a functionality with the jstree-actions.js but I could not implement it this is my code
Thank you very much for the help

```html
<link href="~/Content/jsTree/themes/default/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jsTree3/jstree.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jsTree3/jstree-actions.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#container').jstree({
            'core': {
                "animation": 0,
                "themes": { "stripes": true },
                'data': {
                    'url': B3.Tools.GetRootUrl() + '/jsTree3/GetJsTree3Data?empresa=' + B3.Tools.ObtenerEmpresa('empresa'),
                    'dataType': 'json'
                }

            }
        });

//This is the code that I could not implement

        container.jstree(true).add_action("1", {
            "id": "action_add",
            "class": "action_add pull-right",
            "title": "Add Child",
         "text": "",
            "after": true,
            "selector": "a",
            "event": "click",
            "callback": function (node_id, node, action_id, action_el) {
                console.log("callback", node_id, action_id);
            }
        });

    });


    
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you implement the jstree.actions plugin. Make sure that class icon `action_add` exist.

```
     <script>

        $(function () {
            $('#container').jstree({
                'core': {
                    "animation": 0,
                    "themes": { "stripes": true },
                    'data': {
                        'url': B3.Tools.GetRootUrl() + '/jsTree3/GetJsTree3Data?empresa=' + B3.Tools.ObtenerEmpresa('empresa'),
                        'dataType': 'json'
                    }

                }
            })
            .jstree(true).add_action("1", {
                "id": "action_add",
                "class": "action_add pull-right",
                "title": "Add Child",
                "text": "Edit",
                "after": true,
                "selector": "a",
                "event": "click",
                "callback": function (node_id, node, action_id, action_el) {
                    console.log("callback", node_id, action_id);
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
```